# Docker for parallel tasks

Tags: parallel-processing, docker

I just started with Docker because I'd like to use it to run parallel tasks.
My problem is that I don't understand how Docker handles the resources on the host (CPU, RAM, etc.): i.e. how can I evaluate the maximum number of containers to run at the same time?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: This is a system administration question, and so better suited to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) than here.  But even there, it will need some more specifics to get a meaningful answer.  Leaving aside Docker, how would you evaluate how many services to run on a single bare-metal server?  The only answer possible with the information given is "it depends".

Comment: Yes, you are right. So it's better to close this question? Thanks

Comment: If you can estimate the max RAM required by each container you can limit each container max RAM with --memory, and calculate how many fit in your machine: machine ram = container 1 max ram + container 2 max ram ... leave some spare RAM to the machine os though.
see here: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/